# Cold junction temperature measurement in Multichannel Thermocuple

Tags: signal, temperature, thermocouple

In a multi-channel thermocuple signal conditioner (for example, 5 channels on a single PCB), should I add 5 separate junction temperature measurements to the thermocuple input of each channel to measure the cold junction temperature, or is one temperature sensor on the PCB sufficient?

[image]

[image]